# Application server uses single login to connect to a database

Tags: sql-server

Application server uses single login to connect to a database . There are multiple users connected to the database through the login in that case the information shows only the application login and the host name .

How do i track the individual user that is connected to database through the app server?

Since the dmv only shows the application login and the host name which is same for all the users that are connected.

Comment: What's the application? Do you control it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in this case. SQL has no way to know the windows login using the application account and workstation connecting via application server.

See this answer especially read second answer by Aaron Bertand which explains in details.

[Who is the person using a SQL login?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127477/who-is-the-person-using-a-sql-login)